# How to solve i++ loop error in Python?

Tags: python

My currently code is giving the following error: IndexError: list index out of range so I would like to know if there is any way to use something similar to i++ for loop from java in Python where the code would print "name" + iten from the list for every iten of the list with even positioning.

Sorry if it this seems a bit confusing but as a beginner it is hard to explain somethings :p

ex:

```
i = 0
"name" + list[0]
i = 1
"price" + list[1]
i = 2
"name" + list[2]
```

Code:

```
    import pickle


list1 = []
ans = " "

class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price


while ans != 'no':
    ans = input("Would you like to add a new product, 'yes' or 'no': ")
    if ans == 'no':
        break
    if ans == 'yes':
        name = input("What is your product name?")
        price = input("What is your product price?")
        list1.append(name)
        list1.append(price)


output = open("save1.pkl", 'wb')
pickle.dump(list1, output,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

output.close()

print(" ")

inputFile = open("save1.pkl", 'rb')
list2 = pickle.load(inputFile)
inputFile.close()

for i in range(0,10):
    print("Name:" + list2[i] + " " + "Price:" + list2[i + 1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like you've got a `list` where all the even indices are `name`s, and the odd indices are `price`s. You don't want or need indexing here, because Python has much better solutions to this problem than C. You combine extended slicing with `zip` to iterate them natively in pairs:

```
for name, price in zip(list2[::2], list2[1::2]):
    print("Name:" + name + " " + "Price:" + price)
```

The `list2[::2]` is getting every other element from beginning to end, while `list2[1::2]` gets every other element from index 1 to the end. `zip` then returns `tuple`s of paired values from each slice, so you get the value at index 0 and 1 as your first `name` and `price`, 2 and 3 give your second `name` and `price`, etc. We unpack them into meaningful names in the loop itself, so instead of working with indices of `list2` with cryptic meanings, it's clear we've got a name and a price.

Comment: +1 for not using index loops; Python best practice is usually to avoid them exactly because thinking about your problem at that low level makes it harder to reason about the code, leading to this kind of error.

Comment: This is good learning, thanks! In general, do you think either a dictionary or tuple approach (from the creation of data) would be better for this problem?

Comment: In general, yes, I'd have used a naturally paired structure (either `list` of `tuple`s or a `dict`/`OrderedDict` depending on needs). But it's handy to know how to convert flat data to pairs because sometimes you're not the one generating it.

Answer (score 2):

Python convention is usually to avoid iterating over indexes in this way, exactly because thinking at such a low level tends to lead to these kinds of problems. The reason you're drawn to using indexes in this way is because you're not using an appropriate data structure - as a general rule, the elements of a list should all be conceptually the "same thing" (a name or a price) instead of alternating between those.

You could instead build it as a list of `(name, price)` tuples (conceptually, a list of *products*) by a slight modification to your first loop:

```
    name = input("What is your product name?")
    price = input("What is your product price?")
    product = (name, price)
    list1.append(product)
```

And then your second loop can straightforwardly iterate over these products:

```
for product in list2:
    name, price = product
```

or for short:

```
for name, price in list2:
```

By putting more thought into what kind of data structure you use, you can almost always make the code more straightforward to read and write.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

for i in list2:

i will always be the given member of list2

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is that at some point there **is no next item** in the list.

What kind of behavior do you want on that last object?

Additional: You could use `len(list2)` instead of a hard-coded range value. Something like `for i in range(0, len(list2)):`. In your code, you could do:

```
for i in range(0, len(list2) -1, 2):
  print("Name:" + list2[i] + " " + "Price:" + list2[i + 1])
```

If your list2 was `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` it would print:

```
Name:a Price:b
Name:c Price:d
```

Comment: No need of `first` argument in `range(0, len(list2) -1)`. range(len(list2) -1) is fine.

Comment: The list seems to be pairs, so you don't want to iterate one by one, because then you treat what should only be the first price as the second name, and what should only be the second name as the second price, etc. You could make it work simply by stepping the `range` by 2, but that's still not Pythonic; it's what C programmers who grudgingly use Python do, instead of using native iteration capabilities.

Comment: Good point @ShadowRanger. I did not think about the implications of the Name: Price: combo. I'll edit now!